Combinatorial Proof of the $\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^2 \binom{n}{k} = n(n + 1) 2^{n - 2}$
How to prove that $$\sum_{k = 1}^{n}k^2\binom{n}{k} = n(n + 1)2^{n -2}$$ in an combinatorial way?
I have a algebraic proof method, but I don't know how to use a combinatorial proof method to do it.

You have a set of $n$ people and want to pick a nonempty subset of this set and then pick a leader and treasurer from this group (the leader and the treasurer could be the same person). In how many ways can you do this? One way to count: pick a subset of size $k$ in ${n \choose k}$ different ways, then you have $k$ choices for the leader and $k$ choices for the treasurer, summing over $k$ gives
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n k^2 {n\choose k}
$$
which is the left side of your equation.
Another way to count: either the leader and treasurer are the same or not. If they are the same you pick one person in $n$ possible ways, then you pick an arbitrary (possibly empty) subset for the rest of the group in $2^{n-1}$ different ways. If they are different, you pick the leader and the treasurer in $n(n-1)$ different ways and then pick an arbitrary (possibly empty) subset for the rest of the group in $2^{n-2}$ different ways. Together you get
$$
n 2^{n-1}+n(n-1) 2^{n-2} = (2n+n(n-1))2^{n-2} = n(n+1) 2^{n-2}.
$$
different ways which is the right side of your equation.

Thanks a lot! That's exactly the answer I was looking for! :)
